# with which method .context can be replced in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

as in jQuery 3.0 .context method was removed, what can it be replaced with? I would like to avoid copying removed implementation from old jQuery. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [`.context`](https://api.jquery.com/context/) property was deprecated in jQuery 1.10 and is only maintained to the extent needed for supporting [`.live()`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) in the jQuery Migrate plugin.

The [`.live()`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) method for binding event handlers uses this property to determine the root element to use for its event delegation needs.

For event binding, use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead